# Nodemailer - not blank files sent as blank

Tags: node.js, heroku, fs, nodemailer

I made a simple web app with node.js and hosted it with heroku. The main process does many operations, one of which is reading and writing a text file with ids. However, when I try to send this file from a different process to my email with nodemailer it is sent as blank. The file is initially blank but then is written by the main process; the main process read text from it too so I know the problem is not there. Can you tell me why it isn't working?

Edit: I know for sure that when I send the file is not empty (i do console.log with the content of the file)

Main process code:

```
    function handleSubscriptions(event){
var senderID = event.sender.id;
var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
var timeOfPostback = event.timestamp;
var payload = event.postback.payload;

console.log("Received postback for user %d and page %d with payload '%s' " +
    "at %d", senderID, recipientID, payload, timeOfPostback);

if(payload == "iscrizione"){
    fs.appendFile("./users.txt", senderID + ",", function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The id was appended to file!');
    });

    var data = fs.readFile('./users.txt', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        processData(String(data));
    });

    function processData(data){
        var arr = data.split(",");
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            var val = parseInt(arr[i]);
            msg = "user number " + i + " :"+ val ;
            console.log(msg)
        }
    }

    sendMessage(senderID, "Complimenti, sei iscritto!");
}
    }
```

Sender code:

```
    fs.readFile("./users.txt", function (err, data) {

var message = {
    sender: email,
    to: email,
    subject: 'File user',
    body: 'File in allegato',
    attachments: [{'filename': 'users.txt', 'content': data}]
};

transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        console.log(error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Message 2 sent successfully!');
    transporter.close();
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with concurrency - you are probably reading the file before it is written to.

You need to make sure that you are not reading the values before they are written. Without seeing a single line of code it is impossible to give you any more specific advice than that.

Comment: I updated the question with the code. As I've written, I know that the file is not empty because i output with console.log the content